# Determine ArcGIS version for on RHEL machine

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, rhel5, arcgis-server

I have a machine that is running arcgis but can't determine what version it is.  The documentation I have found so far has been fairly sparse especially with regards to the linux server version of the software.  Does anyone know a way to easily determine the version of arcgis from the command line?

Also if anyone has any good links to command line centric documentation for arcgis it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PatchFinder](http://downloads2.esri.com/Support/downloads/other_/PatchFinder.tar) program.

You can find [help](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/web-based-help) on the arcgis page as well.

Comment: Don't think Patchfinder runs on Linux